# Sending umlauts / special characters using twilio module in parse cloud code

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, twilio

I'm trying to send strings including german special characters (umlauts, Ä Ö Ü ß) via text messages using the Twilio module in Parse Cloud Code.
The strings I receive on the phone are transformed as follows:

> character in source code -> character received on the phone
>
> ä->d, Ä->D, ö->v, Ö->V, ü->ö, Ü->Ö,ß->§

I tried different things like replacing umlauts with unicode codes or parsing the whole String using encodeURIComponent. The file is stored as UTF-8.

Any idea on this? I'd like to continue using the Twilio Module instead of writing a custom wrapper for the Twilio API.

Comment: After Talking to Twilio Support: It seems to be an issue depending on the provider of the receiving phone.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out this twill post: https://www.twilio.com/engineering/2012/11/08/adventures-in-unicode-sms

1. Make sure your language or framework is interpreting percent encoded
   HTTP parameters as UTF-8 and not Latin-1.
2. Make sure your database connection is set to UTF-8. If you're on
   MySQL 5.5 or better, make sure your UTF-8 columns are of type
   utf8mb4 and not utf8. The latter does not have support for non-BMP
   characters as it has a maximum of 3 bytes per character.
3. If you're on MySQL 5.1 and you can't upgrade, you're going to need
   to find your own solution for non-BMP characters. Some options
   include: using a BLOB type and handling encoding/decoding yourself
   or escaping non-BMP characters (whatever scheme you come up with
   must be sure to produce valid UTF-8).
4. In general, do not confuse "strings" and "bytes." If you have a
   collection of bytes, you must know the encoding in order to
   understand it as a string of text.

Also, Twilio officially supports Unicode only: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-languages-are-supported-by-twilio-sms

Comment: thanks, but as the code runs on Parse Cloud and we use their Twilio Module I don't have influence on those factors